# Is $\{a, b\}$ $\subset$ $\{a, b, c\}$ the same thing as $\{\{a, b\}\}$ $\subset$ $\{a, b, c\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It's clear to me that $\{a, b\}$ $\subset$ $\{a, b, c\} = S$.
But I don't see the element $\{\{a, b\}\}$, as a whole, inside $S$.

Comment: Minor nitpick: what you probably meant to say is "But I don't see the element $\{a,b\}$, as a whole, inside $S$": the element doesn't have an the second pair of braces.

Comment: You don't see the element as a whole in S because as a whole it ISN'T in S.  Why would you think it was,

Answer (score 2):

No , A is a subset of B if the elements present in A are also contained in B.

For your first example this is valid as elements a,b are present both in A and B.

However , for your second example the set A= { { a,b } } has a single element as { a,b }.

Hence the correct statement would be { { a,b } } $ \subset $ { { a,b } , c }.

Comment: Thanks!
I'm still confused by the Power Set notation, for reasons explained in Peter's answer, since it seems to imply that $\{\{a, b\}\} \subset S$. I don't see where is my mistake in that notation.

Comment: Your original question doesn't involve power sets, not sure why you are involving that idea here.

Comment: @M.M it appears you are having some confusion regarding the definition of power set . Note that when you say P(S)= $\{ .. , \{a,b\} , ... \}$ , it implies that $\{a,b\} \subset$ S and not $\{\{a,b\}\} \subset$ S.

Comment: @Michael You're right. I got this question reading about powersets. pjs36 Answered the question about powersets anyway, so I won't delete the comments.

Comment: Thanks again, @masterchief, you answered both questions clearly, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

$\{\{a,b\}\} \subset \{a,b,c\}$ is not true, precisely because as you say, the element $\{a,b\}$ is not in $\{a,b,c\}$.

The following modified statement is true: $\{\{a,b\}\} \subset \{a,b,c,\{a,b\}\}$

Comment: Thanks!
This is intuitive for me, but when I have the power set $P(S)$ of $S$,
$P(S)$  = $\{\{a\}, ..., \{a, b\}, ..., \{a, b, c\}\}$. So, by definition, isn't $\{\{a, b\}\} \subset S$?

Comment: @M.M All one can say generally is that $X \in P(S) \implies X \subseteq S$; there is no extra "layer" of braces (i.e., you can't say $\{X\} \subseteq S$). Is that touching on what you're getting at?

Comment: @pjs36 yes, this is exactly what I asked and you answered it clearly. Thanks!